# Реализация MVVM Android

Tags: android, mvvm

Реализую MVVM согласно схеме, представленной ниже. Подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю эту схему:

1. Если мне нужно загрузить данные из внешнего источника и добавить во внутреннее хранилище, то я из Repository обращаюсь к Remote data source, потом из Repository отправляю во внутреннее хранилище?
2. Если я получил данные из внутреннего хранилища, и мне нужно дополнительно произвести с ними какие то дополнительные операции (вычисления), это я тоже делаю в Repository?
3. В Fragment у меня присутствует RecyclerView, в нем выведено несколько EditText которые содержат числа. При изменении одного из чисел в одном из EditText, пересчитывается содержимое остальных EditText этого RecyclerView (все новые данные должны сохраняться в хранилище). Раньше просто всё это у меня лежало в адаптере. Как правильно это реализовать с MVVM (что где должно лежать), т.е. куда будет правильным вынести этот перерасчет, обновление значений адаптера RecyclerView, последующее сохранение значений в хранилище.

Естественно, я смотрел примеры приложений с реализацией MVVM, но все они были слишком простыми, поэтому вопросы выше остались.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В MVVM всё, что касается логики нужно писать внутри ViewModel. Она для этого и предназначена. В больших приложениях как правило отталкиваются от [Clean Architecture](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-clean-architecture-1ad42fcd97fa), в котором чуть больше слоёв. Чтобы дальше было проще объяснить разобью схему выше следующим образом:

Activity/Fragment - слой View

ViewModel - разбивается на несколько слоёв: ViewModel + Interactor (или UseCase)

Все остальные блоки так и остаются

Теперь касательно Ваших вопросов:

1. Да. Все маниипуляции с кэшированием удалённых данных, переключением потоков на IO Thread или трансформацией объекта в вид удобный для дальнейшей работы с объектом - всё это лежит на репозитории. Бизнес-логику в репозитории не пишут, но он отвечает за логику кеширования, сохранения данных и получениие удобного для работы объекта. То есть это некая коробка, которой мы говорим: "Дай нам такой-то объект", но мы не знаем откуда и как он достанет этот объект.
2. Если Вам нужно произвести над объектом какие-то вычисления, не привязанные к контексту Android платформы (В общем, всё что касается бизнес-логики) - это всё пишется в слое Interactor (это отдельный объект, который отвевчает за все вычисления над конкретным объектом).
3. Весь перерасчёт должен находиться в слоё Interactor. Но в итоге должна получиться следующая матрешка:

   - RecyclerAdapter (слой View) - говорит AnyViewModel, что ему надо что-то перерасчитать
   - AnyViewModel (слой ViewModel) - сам перерасчитывает данные, если это что-то завязанное на платформе Android (например если нужно знать размеры каких-то View) или говорит произвести расчёты AnyInteractor (если это общая бизнес-логика)
   - AnyInteractor (слой Interactor) запрашивает текущие данные у AnyRepository и производит расчёты, при необходимости обновляет данные в Repository
     Тем временем слой View подписан через ViewModel на изменение данных в Repository с помощью LiveData. Таким образом как только произведутся все рассчёты, данные во View обновятся. Та самая подписка через LiveData внутри ViewModel - важная часть архитектуры MVVM!

Мне кажется, Вам будет более понятно что и где писать, если вы прочитаете несколько статей по CleanArchitecture (она может ложиться на любую модель MV*)

Comment: Начал разбираться в вашем ответе и гуглить, это Вы мне MVVMi описали уже получается [ссылка](https://medium.com/@thereallukesimpson/clean-architecture-with-mvvmi-architecture-components-rxjava-8c5093337b43)

Comment: @WebFR не знал, что такая существует, всегда пользовался именно такой реализацией, не зная её названия. В таком случае, я думаю, что если поместить весь код внутри Interactor внутрь ViewModel, то получится как раз чистая MVVM.